# Помогите с добавлением в базу данных

Tags: python, sql

Делаю бота для телеграмма и хочу добавить пользователя в sql. Когда добавляю выходит ошибка, что делать?
`cur.execute(f"INSERT INTO users (id, class, liter) VALUES ({id_user}, {class_user}, {litera_user})")`

вылезает ошибка
`cur.execute(f"INSERT INTO users (id, class, liter) VALUES ({id_user}, {class_user}, {litera_user})")`
`sqlite3.OperationalError: near ",": syntax error`

Comment: А вы посмотрите, какой у вас получается sql-запрос

Comment: Вот мне уже даже становится интересно, в какой книжке вас всех учат добавлять параметры в запросы с использованием форматирования строки? `cur.execute(f"INSERT INTO users (id, class, liter) VALUES (?, ?, ?);", (id_user, class_user, litera_user,))`

Answer (score 3):

Проблема скорее всего связана с тем, как вы подставляете параметры в запрос. Ваш код допускает SQL-инъекции и может вызвать ошибки, как вы упоминали, например, если ваши переменные содержат пробелы, запятые или другие символы, которые могут нарушить структуру SQL-запроса.

Вместо форматирования строки Python (f-string), используйте параметризированный запрос, что также является хорошей практикой для предотвращения SQL-инъекций:

```sql
query = "INSERT INTO users (id, class, liter) VALUES (?, ?, ?)"
parameters = (id_user, class_user, litera_user)
cur.execute(query, parameters)
```

В данном случае ? - это универсальный параметр, и его количество должно соответствовать количеству предоставленных параметров.

Обратите внимание, что class является ключевым словом в SQL. Если имя столбца действительно class, вы должны взять его в кавычки ("class") чтобы избежать ошибок. Иначе рекомендуется изменить имя столбца на что-то не являющееся ключевым словом, например class_name.

Также, проверьте ваши типы данных. В SQL, строковые значения должны быть заключены в кавычки. Если class_user и litera_user - строки, и вы используете f-string без кавычек внутри скобок, то это приведет к ошибке. Однако этого можно избежать, используя параметризованный запрос, как показано выше - SQLite автоматически управляет конвертацией типов.